# How to refresh or clear VPN (L2TP) setting in macos

Tags: macos, vpn, l2tp

When I connect the VPN(L2TP), it connect success and any thing is fine,

but when I idle some time or sleep mac

when I connect VPN again, the VPN status still show connect success

but it is no effect

also I can't ping to the server either.

In order to resolve this question

I must to reboot my mac

when I restart the mac.

every will fine again

so, How can I reset some net setting(like restart) to resolve this 
question

Comment: did you find solution?, I have the same problem. thank you

Comment: @whitesiroi see the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your reference, I've found the solution

try Network -> [your net] -> Advanced -> Tick "Send all traffic over VPN connection"

[image]